# JavaScript code in view issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I put JavaScript code in a view file name product/js.blade.php, and include it in another view like

```
{{ HTML::script('product.js') }}
```

I did it because I want to do something in JavaScript with Laravel function, for example

```
var $path = '{{ URL::action("CartController@postAjax") }}';
```

Actually everything is work, but browser throw a warning message, I want to ask how to fix it if possible.

***Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html***

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, putting your Javascript code in a Blade view is risky. Javascript might contain strings by accident that are also Blade syntax and you definitely don't want that to be interpreted.

Secondly, this is also the reason for the browser warning message you get:

Laravel thinks your Javascript is a normal webpage, because you've put it into a Blade view, and therefore it's sent with this header...

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

If you name your file `product.js` and instead of putting it in your view folder you drop it into your javascript asset folder, it will have the correct header:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

.. and the warning message will be gone.

EDIT:

If you want to pass values to Javascript from Laravel, use this approach:

Insert this into your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPath = '{{ URL::action("CartController@postAjax") }}';
</script>
```

And then use the variable in your external script.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and advise, I got two questions

1. How to make *.js file can user Laravel function as I want?
2. How to use HTML::script to include, ../app/views/*.js will work, but I don't think it right

Comment: Don't put Javascript files in `/app/views`, put them in `public/assets/javascript`.

Comment: I put them in assets/js/ in the first place, but I can't use Laravel function by that.

Comment: What do you mean, Laravel function? I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: $path = '{{ URL::action("CartController@postAjax") }}'; I did it in js.blade.php response "http://localhost/public/cart/ajax/", in x.js response '{{ URL::action("CartController@postAjax") }}' XD

Comment: Don't use Laravel function right inside Javascript. You should define global Javascript variables in your view and use them in external Javascript. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that CartController@postAjax returns the content type of javascript and you should be good to go. Something like this:

```
#CartController.php
protected function postAjax() {
....
$contents = a whole bunch of javascript code;
$response = Response::make($contents, '200');
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for, but here is a way to map ajax requests to laravel controller methods pretty easily, without having to mix up your scripts, which is usually not the best way to do things.

I use these kinds of calls to load views via ajax into a dashboard app.The code looks something like this.

AJAX REQUEST (using jquery, but anything you use to send ajax will work)

```
$.ajax({

    //send post ajax request to laravel
    type:'post',

    //no need for a full URL. Also note that /ajax/ can be /anything/.
    url: '/ajax/get-contact-form',

    //let's send some data over too.
    data: ajaxdata,

    //our laravel view is going to come in as html
    dataType:'html'

}).done(function(data){

    //clear out any html where the form is going to appear, then append the new view.
    $('.dashboard-right').empty().append(data);

    });
```

LARAVEL ROUTES.PHP

```
Route::post('/ajax/get-contact-form', 'YourController@method_you_want');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function method_you_want(){

if (Request::ajax())
{
     $data = Input::get('ajaxdata');

     return View::make('forms.contact')->with('data', $data);
}
```

I hope this helps you... This controller method just calls a view, but you can use the same method to access any controller function you might need.

This method returns no errors, and is generally much less risky than putting JS in your views, which are really meant more for page layouts and not any heavy scripting / calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getWebServices() {   
$content = View::make("_javascript.webService", $data);

    return (new Response($content, 200))->header('Content-Type', "text/javascript");
}
```

return the above in a method of your controller

and write your javascript code in your webService view inside _javascript folder.
Instead of loading get datas via ajax, I create js blade with that specific data and base64_encode it, then in my js code, I decode and use it.